# how to get all the file list from all directory in default path in java

Tags: java

these are the folders in my default path in java

```
module1/
module2/
```

in module1 there are files with file name as following :

```
java.txt
php.txt
```

in module2 there are files with file name as following :

```
mySQL.txt
Javascript.txt
```

i want to check the existence of a file identified by user input

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String uInput;
System.out.println("enter file to check"):
sc.nextLine();
File f = new File(uInput+".txt");
```

for example uInput is "mySQL" then the expected output is as following :

```
mySQL exists in FOLDER module2
```

and if uInput is "C++" then the expected output is as following :

```
C++ does not exist in module1 , module2
```

Comment: What is *the default path in Java* ? I never came across such thing earlier!

Comment: Read the javadoc of java.io.File, read tutorials on IO, try something, and get back here if you're stuck, showing what you tried. We won't do your homework.

Comment: @shekharsuman in this case i'm using NetBeans platform and what i meant is NetBeans default folder which is Document/Netbeans/Projectname , it doesn't matter anyway

Comment: What's stopping your from testing whether your `uInput+".txt"` exists in folder `module1` or in `module2`?

Comment: @TheGIndonesia-You should properly edit the question along with proper tags like `netbeans`,etc. else you may receive several downvotes and this question may close too!

Comment: @shekharsuman netbeans is irrelevant. The Java code needed to implement this isn't different if you create it using eclipse, IntelliJ or Notepad.

Comment: @JBNizet-Actually,the default directory in netbeans goes as `.../NetBeansProjects/ProjectName/src`. So,I guess it might be different for different IDE's and so OP won't get the exact response! So,for more certainity,he should add the `netbeans` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to walkthrough directories to search for file. So something like:

```
public static void walkThroughDir( String path, String fname ) {
    File root = new File( path );
    File[] list = root.listFiles();

    if (list == null) return;

    for ( File f : list ) {
        if ( f.isDirectory() ) {
          walkThroughDir( f.getAbsolutePath(), fname );
        }
        else {
          if (f.getName().equals(fname)) {
            System.out.println( "File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() );
            return;
          }
    }
  }
```

}

And call it with method like

```
uInput = sc.nextLine();
walkThroughDir("C:\\softwares\\eclipse", uInput + ".txt");
```

Answer (score -3):

just use isFile.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
File f = new File(s.nextLine());
if (f.isFile()) {
    // file exist
}
```